# SQL Data Source vs Data Tables/Data Set

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I normally use **SQL Data Source** to do DataBase transactions ie **CRUD** operations.

Is it wise to use SQL Data Source over **DataTables** or **Data Set** ??

Comment: Go with the one that helps you easily separate your data logic from presentation. I think dataset/datatable does. I believe there are similar questions on StackOverflow, so search

Comment: Which one is better performance wise??

Comment: You can [measure](http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html) that yourself. And do the testing in Release mode.